# Pretty ClockGauge: how to remove Second needle?

Tags: gui-construction

I have the following `ClockGauge`:

```
ClockGauge["Sun 2 Oct 2016 00:30", GaugeLabels -> Placed[ "DateTimeShort", Below], LabelStyle -> Bold, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15]]
```

which is displayed as:

[image: ClockGauge]

How can I remove the Second needle? It really looks ugly with it.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, RTFM:

```
GaugeMarkers -> {Automatic, Automatic, None}
```